# Can I power a single pole switch from the end of a 3 way?

Tags: switch

I've done the imaginable and forgot to run one more line to the gang box.  Is there any hope I can pull power from the other 3 way switch also in the box?  I've attached the diagram of how its currently wired and what I'm hoping can happen.
[image: 3 way to single pole]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. You need access to the white wire (neutral) coming into the first box from the load center and continuing to the existing lights. Since that is not in the second box, you have nothing to connect to the return from the new light.

Comment: I was already resigned to that answer so I appreciate you confirming it.